# How to prove this inequality with exponents?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, inequality, holder-inequality

Let $G = |Q_1+Q_2|^{p-1}(Q_1+Q_2) - |Q_1|^{p-1}Q_1-|Q_2|^{p-1}Q_2$
where $Q_1,Q_2:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$ are positive valued functions and $p>2.$
I want to show that,
$$|G| \leq K\left( |Q_1|^{p-1} |Q_2| + |Q_2|^{p-1} |Q_1|\right)$$
where $K$ is some constant that we don't really care about. I tried the following,
\begin{align}
|G| &\leq |Q_1+Q_2|^{p} + |Q_1|^{p}+|Q_2|^{p}\\
&\leq 2^{p-1}(|Q_1|^{p} + |Q_2|^{p}) + (|Q_1|^{p} + |Q_2|^{p})\\
&\leq (2^{p-1}+1) (|Q_1|^{p} + |Q_2|^{p}).
\end{align}
But this is not good. Any hints/comments would be much appreciated.

Comment: $K\geq 0$. At the moment, one idea that came to me was the triangle inequality, but it might not work.

Comment: $$\implies G=|Q_1+ Q_2|^p-|Q_1|^p-|Q_2|^p=(Q_1+Q_2)^p-(Q_1^p+Q_2^p)=\sum_{i=0}^p\binom {p}{i}Q_1^iQ_2^{p-i}-(Q_1^p+Q_2^p)=\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\binom {p}{i}Q_1^iQ_2^{p-i}$$ But, consider: $$\mathcal R_{Q_1},\mathcal R_{Q_2}\in \mathbb C\setminus \mathbb R$$ which isn't the best notation for the non-real complex numbers.

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya I made an edit. The functions $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are not complex-valued.  So $|Q_1|$, for instance, is just the absolute value of $Q_1.$ I apologize for this error.

Comment: it's ok, don't worry, it happens to everyone who works. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that,
$$G = |Q_1+Q_2|^{p-1}(Q_1+Q_2) - |Q_1|^{p-1}Q_1-|Q_2|^{p-1}Q_2$$
and so if $|Q_2|<|Q_1|$ then if we let $x= Q_2/Q_1$ then we get that,
\begin{align*}
    |G| &\leq |Q_1|^{p}|(1+x)^p - 1- x^p| \\
        &\lesssim |Q_1|^{p} |x|\\
        &\lesssim |Q_1|^{p-1}|Q_2|.
 \end{align*}
Similarly, if $|Q_1|<|Q_2|$ then we have that,
\begin{align*}
    |G| &\lesssim |Q_2|^{p-1}|Q_1|.
\end{align*}
and so we get that, 
$$|G|\lesssim |Q_2||Q_1|^{p-1} + |Q_1||Q_2|^{p-1}.$$